# When to use @RestController vs @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have been looking at various examples of how to use Spring with **REST**.  Our end target is a Spring `HATEOAS/HAL` setup

I have seen two distinct methods for rendering **REST** within ***Spring***

1. Via `@RestController` within a Controller
2. Via `@RepositoryRestResource` within a Repository

The thing I am struggling to find is why would you use one over the other. When trying to implement `HAL` which is best?

Our database backend is **Neo4j**.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Ok, so the short story is that you want to use the `@RepositoryRestResource` since this creates a **HATEOAS** service with **Spring JPA**.

As you can see [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/) adding this annotation and linking it to your Pojo you have a fully  functional **HATEOAS** service without having to implement the repository method or the REST service methods

If you add the `@RestController` then you have to implement each method that you want to expose on your own and also it does not export this to a **HATEOAS** format.

Comment: By default, Spring Data REST will export ALL top-level, public interface repositories. You only need @RepositoryRestResource to either NOT export an interface, or to alter the details of the endpoint.

Comment: If you use RestController with Spring Data REST, you will sidestep EVERYTHING Spring Data REST provides. To code a custom Spring MVC controller that uses Spring data REST's message converters, etc., look into BasePathAwareController.

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is correct @gregturn has the better answer.

Answer (score 42):

There is a third (and fourth) option that you have not outlined, which is to use either @BasePathAwareController or @RepositoryRestController, depending on whether you are performing entity-specific actions or not.

@RepositoryRestResource is used to set options on the public Repository interface - it will automatically create endpoints as appropriate based on the type of Repository that is being extended (i.e. CrudRepository/PagingAndSortingRepository/etc).

@BasePathAwareController and @RepositoryRestController are used when you want to manually create endpoints, but want to use the Spring Data REST configurations that you have set up.

If you use @RestController, you will create a parallel set of endpoints with *different* configuration options - i.e. a different message converter, different error handlers, etc - but they will happily coexist (and probably cause confusion).

Specific documentation can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

Comment: I think this is no longer true. If a `@RestController` uses the same path as a `@RepositoryRestResource`, the repository endpoints won't be created.

Answer (score 23):

Well, above answers are correct in their context still I am giving you practical example.

In many scenarios as a part of API we need to provide endpoints for searching an entity based on certain criteria.  Now using JPA you don't have to even write queries, just make an interface and methods with specific nomenclature of Spring-JPA.  To expose such APIs you will make Service layer which would simply call these repository methods and finally Controllers which will expose endpoints by calling Service layer.

What Spring did here, allow you to expose these endpoints from such interfaces (repositories) which are generally GET calls to search entity and in background generates necessary files to create final endpoints.  So if you are using @RepositoryRestResource then there is no need to make Service/Controller layer.

On the other hand @RestController is a controller that specifically deals with json data and rest work as a controller.  In short @Controller + @ResponseBody = @RestController.

Hope this helps.

See my working example and blog for the same: 

http://sv-technical.blogspot.com/2015/11/spring-boot-and-repositoryrestresource.html 

https://github.com/svermaji/Spring-boot-with-hibernate-no-controller

Comment: I can see people going to my blog, if this solution works please up vote.

Answer (score 11):

`@RepositoryRestController` override default generated Spring Data REST controllers from exposed repository.

> To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more, use the `@RepositoryRestController` annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC `@Controller` or `@RestController`

E.g this controllers use `spring.data.rest.basePath` Spring Boot setting as base path for routing.

See [Overriding Spring Data REST Response Handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers).

Be aware of adding `@ResponseBody` as it is missed in `@RepositoryRestController`

If you not exposed repository (marked as `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`), use `@BasePathAwareController` annotation instead

Also be aware of bags

[`ControllerLinkBuilder` does not take Spring Data REST's base path into account and `@RequestMapping` shouldn't be used on class/type level](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/434)

and

[Base path doesn't show up in HAL](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-748)

Workaround to fix link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736503/548473

UPDATE: at last I prefer not to use `@RepositoryRestController` due to lot of workarounds.