# Base path doesn't appear in ResourceProcessor custom links

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

In Spring Data REST I'm creating custom links using a `ResourceProcessor`:

```
@Component
public class ServiceInstanceProcessor
        implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<ServiceInstance>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<ServiceInstance> process(Resource<ServiceInstance> resource) {
        Long id = resource.getContent().getId();
        ServiceInstanceController controller =
                methodOn(ServiceInstanceController.class);

        resource.add(linkTo(controller.getNodeSummary(id))
                .withRel("nodeSummary"));
        resource.add(linkTo(controller.getHealthBreakdown(id))
                .withRel("healthBreakdown"));
        resource.add(linkTo(controller.getRotationBreakdown(id))
                .withRel("rotationBreakdown"));
        return resource;
    }
}
```

However the generated links don't include the base path, even though I've marked the controller as `@BasePathAwareController` and even though the default links do include the base path:

```
{
  ...

  "_links" : {
  "self" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/serviceInstances/101"
  },
  "serviceInstance" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/serviceInstances/101{?projection}",
    "templated" : true
  },
  "nodeSummary" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/serviceInstances/101/nodeSummary"
  },
  "healthBreakdown" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/serviceInstances/101/healthBreakdown"
  },
  "rotationBreakdown" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/serviceInstances/101/rotationBreakdown"
  },

  ...
}
```

}

Is there anything else I need to do to get the base path to appear in the links?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is connected with bug [ControllerLinkBuilder does not take Spring Data REST's base path into account](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/434) and [Custom Controller + changed base path doesn't show up in HAL](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-748)

As workaround I do next:

```
@Autowired
private final RepositoryRestConfiguration config;

private Link fixLinkSelf(Object invocationValue) {
    return fixLinkTo(invocationValue).withSelfRel();
}

@SneakyThrows
private Link fixLinkTo(Object invocationValue) {
    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = linkTo(invocationValue).toUriComponentsBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString());
    uriComponentsBuilder.replacePath(config.getBasePath() + url.getPath());
    return new Link(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString());
}
```

usage is the same as `linkTo`:

```
resources.add(fixLinkSelf(methodOn(VoteController.class).history()));    
resources.add(fixLinkTo(methodOn(VoteController.class).current()).withRel("current"));
```

Other workaround for simple case based on current request with addPath:

```
new Link(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path(addPath).build().toUriString())
```