# Rest Controllers vs spring-data-rest RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I know this might feel like a duplicate of this.
[When to use @RestController vs @RepositoryRestResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824840/when-to-use-restcontroller-vs-repositoryrestresource)
But I have a few things which were not addressed in that question.

1. With `@RepositoryRestResource`, every method is by default exposed. Which I feel is a bit annoying. Correct me if I am wrong here. For example in the below case

   ```
   @RepositoryRestResource  
   public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {}
   ```

If I want only findAll() and findOne() to be exposed and not any other methods, especially delete.  To achieve this I need to do something like this

```
    @RepositoryRestResource
    public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, String> {
      @RestResource(exported = false)
      @Override
      default void delete(String s) {
      }
      @RestResource(exported = false)
      @Override
      default void delete(Product product) {
      }
      @RestResource(exported = false)
      @Override
      default void delete(Iterable<? extends Product> iterable) {
      }
      @RestResource(exported = false)
      @Override
      default void deleteAll() {
      }
    }
```

Which I feel is really lot of unwanted code. This is much better to do with Rest Controller approach

2. I believe it is better to return any value from REST endpoints using ResponseEntity. But with spring-data-rest approach, I am not sure how to do it.
3. I could not find any way to unit test(Not IT) REST endpoints exposed by the RepositoryRestResource. But with REST controller approach, I can test my REST endpoints using `MockServletContext`, `MockMvc`, `MockMvcBuilders`

Given all these, is it still advantageous to use sping-data-rest(except for HATEOS)?
please clarify

Comment: I think it would be better to split your points into different questions.

Comment: Hi,  You mean one question for each of these points? Thanks

Comment: Yes, usually it's much easier to find answers to direct questions on SO. This also helps others who search for similar topics.

Answer (score 19):

Spring-data-rest is about providing REST endpoints for data repositories and it does provides solid REST with all bells and whistles including ALPS metadata, search endpoints, etc. This usually covers most use cases and provides basis for customisations.

Here're some hints.

**Regarding p.1)** - Customising exported resources and methods.

You do not need to put `@RestResource(exported = false)` on all `delete(...)` methods because only one is actually exported: `void delete(Product entity)`. Look into [relevant documentation chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources) and the source code. If i do not miss something, you just need to provide these:

- `findAll(Pageable)`
- `findOne(id)`
- `save(Entity)`
- `delete(Entity)`

**A note about exported repository methods.** Sometimes it's easier to extend a very basic (empty) `Repository<Product, String>` repository interface and provide only methods you allow on the repository, for example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, String> {
  long count();
  Page<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
  Product findOne(String entity);
  <S extends Product> S save(S entity);
}
```

**Regarding a custom controller.** To customise a default behaviour the easiest is to annotate controllers with `@RespositoryRestController`. Check-out docs and look into [RepositoryEntityController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) - that's the default controller.

**Regarding p.2)** Returning ResponseEntity from controllers

It's very straingforward. You can wrap entity into `Resource<T>` (e.g. using a `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`) and create a `ResponseEntity` with it. See [RepositoryEntityController.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) and some examples, like [spring-restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springsource/restbucks/payment/web/PaymentController.java).

**Regarding p.3)** - Testing rest endpoints

REST endpoints that expose the RepositoryRestResource are implemented in the `RepositoryEntityController` (part of the spring-data-rest).

If you implement your own custom controller, you can add **unit tests** as usual but things get more complex if you use `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler`.

Unit test example:

```
public class FooControllerTests {

  @Mock
  PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler;

  @Mock
  PersistentEntityResourceAssemblerArgumentResolver assemblerResolver;

  @Mock
  PersistentEntity<Foo, ?> entity;

  @InjectMocks
  FooController fooController;

  @Mock
  FooService fooService;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Rule
  public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(fooController)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(assemblerResolver)
        .build();
  }

  @Test
  public void test_GetItem_Success() throws Exception {
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    
    when(fooService.findOne(1)).thenReturn(foo);
    when(assemblerResolver.supportsParameter(any())).thenReturn(true);
    when(assemblerResolver.resolveArgument(any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(assembler);
    when(assembler.toResource(foo))
        .thenReturn(PersistentEntityResource.build(foo, entity).build());
    
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/foo/1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}
```

See also ["Building REST services with Spring" tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi aux, thanks for the detailed explanation. Just a couple of follow ups. Regarding point 2 and 3. In Point 2 What I meant is  returning ResponseEntity from Repository(RepositoryRestResource) not Controller class. One of the key things in using spring-data-rest is avoiding writing controllers. Returning ResponseEntity from controller is pretty straight forward. But If I have to write controller myself then why would I use spring-data-rest. Regarding point 3 if you look at my question, I have categorically mentioned unit tests and Not IT(integration tests)   Thanks

Comment: p2. Returning ResponseEntity from a Repository would be odd solution. ResponseEntity represents the HTTP response.

Comment: The spring-data-rest provides you with solid default implementation of REST API for your data and possibilities to extend and customise it. No need to write standard CRUD controllers, etc. Only if the standard impl is not enough then you start writing a custom controller as the last resort. Mostly you use other means of customisation. If you have really special needs for request processing, probably you have to write some sample code and evaluate it for your project.

Comment: P2. I completely agree returning ResponseEntity from Repository would be a odd solution. But I always understood that returning ResponeEntity is a good thing from a REST endpoints. So keeping that in mind, using spring-data-rest defeats the purpose. isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: P3. Ya true, unit testing spring-data-rest endpoints will be redundant since the endpoints are generated by the framework. But  the reason I was thinking of writing unit tests is to improve code coverage. Thanks

Comment: P2. There must be some confusion. The spring-data-rest provides endpoints. Using ResponseEntity or some other response - it does not matter. It's not always "good thing" to return ResponseEntity - it just depends on what you need. You can search for questions like "When to return ResponseEntity from controller method?", e.g. this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549379/when-use-responseentityt-and-restcontroller-for-spring-restful-applications.